# When is clock deskewing useful on an FPGA?

Tags: clock, xilinx, skew

The UltraScale Architecture Clocking Resources User Guide (UG572) has a [section](https://docs.xilinx.com/r/en-US/ug572-ultrascale-clocking/Clock-Network-Deskew?tocId=6wv3ynZd0_14xnTqdjNmdA) on a MMCM configuration that enables skew removal, and says

> One of the predominant uses of the MMCM is for clock network deskew

I understand the issues that clock skew can cause, namely reducing the allowed slack for a signal to propagate, and making timing closure more difficult.

I have asked a similar [question on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/FPGA/comments/178hzyv/comment/k500wyd/?context=3) but the answer I got confused me more on the input data path, which I think is a bit outside the scope of the deskewing.

Here's the configuration:

[image]

I now find only one good reason for doing this, and that is to ensure that the clk5 (to the logic) has a specific phase relationship (in this case 0) with the input clock, which I don't think it must be coming from a chip pin input. The BUFG on the feedback path just makes sure that the leaves of the clock distribution are in phase with the CLKIN of the MMCME. And the advantage is clear, to have better slack budget during STA between clk1 and clk5, if there is any synchronous clock crossing.

Is there another reason why I would deskew the clock? The user that helped me on reddit was talking about deskewing an input clock to sample some input data, but I am not sure I understand.